# Button not display below RecycleView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

A layout is designed using `RecycleView` to display images. A button is added below `RecycleView` to save the selected items from the list.button is not visible not in Design View nor when I run the app . Couldn't trace where the problem is. The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.user.recycleview.imagesview">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/titlebar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<view
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/savebutton"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12pt" />


<!--
Deleted fab element
-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** Add a `RelativeLayout` below `AppBarLayout` and put `Button` and `RecyclerView` inside `RelativeLayout`.

**2.** Add attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to `Button` to align it at the `bottom` of screen.

**3.** Add attribute `android:layout_above="@id/button7"` to `RecyclerView` to show it above `Button`.

**Update your layout as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/button7"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer seems useful, you can vote it up. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the recyclerview as `fill_parent`. So it will occupy the full screen, and the button will not be visible. Try using weights as mentioned below.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

You can use weights to give dynamic height

```
<LinearLayout ...
android:layout_weight="10">

   <view
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130px"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can set the height dynamically in java by [calculating the height of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: How can i set to fixed height as the display changes as per the mobile piece dimensions. Please correct me i understood it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Your not able to see the button because you have set `height` of your `RecyclerView` to `fill_parent`.

There are several ways to solve this problem:
Change the `height` to `wrap_content` or set

1. Change the `height` to `wrap_content` or set a fixed `height`
2. Use `RelativeLayout` as base layout and for `RecyclerView` add `layout_above` attribute. So that `RecyclerView` doesn't push your `Button` below.
3. Use 1st and add margin/padding

Note: You should use `match_parent` as `fill_parent` is now deprecated

Comment: Change to RelativeLayout and added layout_above. Still the button is not diplayed. Also tried by adding layout_below to button, not working

Comment: I'll send you the complete layout till evening

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks akshay for the support